# flex-direction: row is not working; it's still displaying as a column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a nav bar that I want to display as a column on small screens and as a row on desktop screen sizes. My problem is that I do not know why "flex-direction: row;" won't change the nav bar to fit side by side.

```css
.top-nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #333;
}
.top-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.top-nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 750px) {
  /* top nav */
  .top-nav {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .top-nav li {
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="top-nav">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a>Category</a></li>
      <li><a>Recent</a></li>
      <li><a>All recipes</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I just had this problem, but for a different reason. No matter how many times I looked at the CSS I couldn't see anything wrong. Turns out my text editor added a closing `</div>` tag in the HTML that I didn't catch.

Answer (score 7):

Problem in your selector scope. Your `flex` is not working at all to manage your nav item layout. You applying CSS the navigation container not the menu item container. Even when it is showing as a column this is also not credit of `flex` property here. See below it may help you:

The key part is:

```
.top-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```css
.top-nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #333;
}

.top-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.top-nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 750px) {

  /* top nav */

  .top-nav {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  
  .top-nav ul {
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .top-nav li {
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
  }
```

```html
<div class="top-nav">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a>Category</a></li>
      <li><a>Recent</a></li>
      <li><a>All recipes</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, your snippet gives me the same layout as one in question.

Answer (score 4):

Following changes in Your CSS For solution

```css
.top-nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #333;
}

.top-nav {
 text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.top-nav ul 
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) 
{

.top-nav ul 
{

   flex-direction:column;
}

  
  .top-nav li
  {
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
  }
  


}
```

```html
<div class="top-nav">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a>Category</a></li>
      <li><a>Recent</a></li>
      <li><a>All recipes</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply `flex-direction: row` to `ul`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21621637)

Comment: @PankajMakwana How so? I believe this is exactly what OP is looking for

Comment: @Zer0 You are correct, this is exactly what OP was missing, I'm not sure what Pankaj is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your `<li>`'s children of a `display: flex` parent. Move your `top-nav` class to the `<ul>` and that should do it.

```
<div>
  <nav>
    <ul class="top-nav">
      <li><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a>Category</a></li>
      <li><a>Recent</a></li>
      <li><a>All recipes</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Here's my favorite flexbox cheatsheet: https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 0):

> Now flex-direction:column; work in max width 750px and flex-direction:row work after 750px;

[see the js fiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/razibmahmud50/f483Lxkr/)

```css
.top-nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #333;
}

.top-nav {
  
}

.top-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {

  /* top nav */

  .top-nav ul{
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .top-nav li {
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
  }
  }
```

```html
<div class="top-nav">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a>Category</a></li>
      <li><a>Recent</a></li>
      <li><a>All recipes</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code Hope this will work for you!

```css
.top-nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #333;
}
.top-nav ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.top-nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  /* top nav */
.top-nav ul { flex-direction: column; }
}
/* .top-nav li {
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
  }
} */
```

```html
<div class="top-nav">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a>Category</a></li>
      <li><a>Recent</a></li>
      <li><a>All recipes</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain in your answer what you changed that fixed it?